# Game completion achievements and multiplayer

Tags: achievements, dungeon-siege-3

If you complete the main quest in a multi-player game, do all the players get the achievement for completing the quest as the character they are currently playing?  Or does only the host get the achievement for their "main character"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, everybody playing will get the achievement for that character and difficulty, even if they only joined that game before the final boss. (You could even get the game completion trophies like this before you got the other trophies for certain parts of the story, like going through the Mournweald.)

Comment: Cool, that makes for a nice way around having to replay the entire game for those that don't want to do so.