# Can Worthy of Legend in Dungeon Siege III be cheesed?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-siege-3

The trophy for *Worthy of Legend* reads:

> You completed Dungeon Siege III at the highest difficulty level.

Does this mean I have to start the game at Hardcore difficulty and never set it to an easier level? Or does it just mean I need to complete the final encounter at Hardcore difficulty, allowing me to play at Casual difficulty up to that point?

Comment: It amazes me that they didn't simply restrain you from changing the difficulty mid-playthrough, if they're going to have achievements for it. I'm thinking of other games that have these kinds of achievements, they always restrain you from mid-playthrough difficulty changes.

Comment: @Grace Dragon Age allowed you to change your difficulty at will, and its DLC had difficulty level 'chieves, but they also specifically said which encounter you needed to beat at X difficulty in order to get it: "Defeated the Harvester on Hard difficulty" and such. There's a lot of stuff in DS3 that points to a severe lack of attention to detail, unfortunately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[You don't even have to play the rest of the game at all](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/25151/game-completion-achievements-and-multiplayer/).  So yes, all that matters is the difficulty level at the time of beating the last encounter.

Comment: Unless it requires that game to have always been on hardcore, that is. (Although I do doubt it.)